# Google Chrome Speech-to-Text API JavaScript Continuous Doesn't Work?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, speech-recognition

I am creating a basic speech-to-text website. It only needs to work in Google Chrome, so I'm using the simple chrome speech-to-text API. It activates for a second and then disables. My code is simple:

```
    var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
    recognition.continuous = true;
    recognition.interimResults = true;
    final_transcript = '';
    recognition.onresult = function (event) {
        var interim_transcript = '';

        for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
            if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
                final_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
            } else {
                interim_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("write").value = final_transcript;
        recognition.start();
    };
    recognition.start();
```

For some reason, a problem occurs. It worked perfectly a day ago. All answers are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a similar task and implemented it by calling `recognition.stop()` on the `onresult` handler and `recognition.start()` on the `onend` handler.

Comment: This works to keep the program going, but now it doesn't do anything with the event value. Is this related?

Comment: What do you mean? do you get to the `onresult` handler and something is wrong there?

Comment: Try adding `recognition.onerror` and call there `recognition.stop()` as well.

Comment: I don't get to the onresult handler.